# Can I point a limited number of subdomains to a subdirectory using DNS?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain, cname, subdirectory

I have taken my domain `Freenom.com` (a domain provider) and hosted it on `Sixserve.com` (a hosting service). The problem is that this hosting service allows only 3 sub-domains for per hosting plan, and I want to increase this limit.

I have full control over my domain and can change any DNS records at my will (including `CNAME`, `A`, etc...). So, my question is: Is it possible to change my DNS records (or otherwise) in such a way that a sub-domain `subdomain.example.com` will point to `example.com/somepage`. Is this possible, if yes then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to change my DNS records (or otherwise) in such a way that a sub-domain subdomain.example.com will point to example.com/somepage.

Not by changing DNS records. `A` records point to [IP addresses](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090#H). `CNAME` records point to another [host](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090#K). Neither can point to a URL or URI like: `example.com/somepage`.

However, some DNS providers (like domain registrars) offer domain *forwarding* to URLs which uses a `301` redirect, or *masking* which uses a frame. Looking at the [features](http://www.freenom.com/en/freeandpaiddomains.html) for `freenom.com`, it appears they do offer URL forwarding, however it is unclear if they offer forwarding for *subdomains* like [some registrars do](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name?countrysite=us#add).

> The problem is that this hosting service allows only 3 sub-domains for per hosting plan, and I want to increase this limit.

If your goal is to increase the number of subdomains, then adding a free CDN like [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) will allow to you to create additional subdomains using `CNAME` records, or [wildcards DNS entries](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168826-Does-CloudFlare-support-wildcard-DNS-entries-) (i.e., `*.example.com`) so that you can use any subdomain you like.

Combined with CloudFlare's [Page Rules](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-fine-grained-feature-co/), you could then point added subdomains to another URL (e.g., `subdomain.example.com` -> `example.com/somepage`).

Comment: Well, my domain is already connected with Cloud Flare, so I will check up with that... Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, no problem.

Comment: Will you help me with some example, I'm finding it a little unclear. What exactly I have to do in may Cloud Flare control panel in page rules, so that, example.mysite.com will point to mysite.com/somepage. Please?

Comment: Create the subdomain you want to redirect by adding a `CNAME`, and then create a Page Rule for it as covered in the first example under the _Rule Effects_ section of the Page Rules tutorial [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-). You'll want to set the reverse of that Page Rule however, from subdomain -> deep link. Good luck.